# VLOOKUP not looking up based on individual cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to do a VLOOKUP on Excel, from side tabs into a main tab through macro functions.

This is how it works:

**1) **Users will enter Item number on their individual Excel Sheets****
[image: Anon Sheet]

**2) Excel Function will VLOOKUP information from each side sheet into the Main Tab**

[image: Main Tab]

However, as you can see from the image above, the VLOOKUP Macro is filling all the cells up with the VLOOKUP from the first row.

Even though the VLOOKUP have selected the individual row numbers, **it still does not show the correct VLOOKUP value**

[image: Sample]

My code for the Macro in VBA is as follows:

```vb
Sub VLookupAnon()
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
   
    
    ' Loop through each row and perform the VLOOKUP
    For i = 2 To 10
        ' Get the lookup value from column A
        Dim lookupValue As Variant
        lookupValue = Cells(i, "A").Value
        
        ' Perform VLOOKUP and insert the result into the corresponding N cell
        Cells(i, "B").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A" & i & ",CHOOSE({1,2},'Anon'!A2:A10,'Anon'!B2:B10),2,FALSE)"
    Next i
End Sub
```

Do let me know if there are any issues with my code and how I can improve on it, thank you!

Comment: Why are you using choose in your VLOOKUP function? In a VLOOKUP you can already have multiple columns wherein you specify which one (numbered from left to right) you'd want as the returned value. CHOOSE would be used here if you wanted to reverse the columns so you could search from the right and get a column on its left returned. In your VLOOKUP it'd be `=VLOOKUP(A3,Anon!A2:B10,2,FALSE)`. Secondly, the VLOOKUP will give you the first found value (in this case Item1) so this is no surprise. Secundary question: the user types in his items and wants to find those from others sheets?